# How can I install Kindle app on an iOS 9.3.5 iPad?

Tags: ipad

How can I get a download a copy of Kindle App for a iOS 9.3.5 iPad 3rd generation?  The one in the app store requires ios 10.

Comment: You may also find this recent discussion in another forum useful in your specific case.    https://www.amazonforum.com/forums/digital-content/appstore/472656-kindle-app-wont-install-on-ipad-with-ios-version-9?page=2